# Getting auth to work in a package

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to follow the guide here: http://fideloper.com/post/41750468389/laravel-4-uber-quick-start-with-auth-guide to set up authorisation for users going to 'admin/'. However I'm trying to do it in a package which is proving tricky.

in workbench/vendor/user/src/Vendor/User/routes.php I have:

```
Route::filter('adminAuth', function()    {
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('user::login');
});

Route::get('/login', function()    {
    return View::make('user::login');
});

Route::post('/login', function()    {
    Auth::attempt( ['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' =>       Input::get('password')] );
    return Redirect::to('/');
});

Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'adminAuth', function()    {
    return 'Hello, '.Auth::user()->email.'!';
}));
```

The login page displays as expected and when entering the user information I seeded the db with I get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class '\User' not found in E:\cms_root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php line 89
```

In the auth.php file in the app I have:

```
    'model' => 'User',
```

which I'm guessing is incorrect, but I'm not sure how to address the User model I have created in: `workbench/vendor/user/src/Vendor/User/models/User.php`. I've tried `User::User` and `Vendor\User\User` neither of which work.

Added:

The User.php file has `<?php namespace Vendor\User;` at the top, and I have done a composer dumpautoload in both the app root and workbench/vendor/user folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try using \Vendor\User\User? The preceding backslash is like tha absolute path equivalent of a namespace.

Comment: Hi, thanks I just tried changing it to: `'model' => '\Vendor\User\User',` and it still throws an error: `FatalErrorException: Error: Class '\Vendor\User\User' not found in E:\cms_root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php line 89`

Comment: @Al_ Are you literally writing `'\Vendor\User\User'`? Because you need to escape \ like this: `'\\Vendor\\User\\User'`. Otherwise something is wrong with autoloading.

Comment: It was down to the namespacing, I should have had the namespace of the model as `<?php namespace Vendor\User\Models;` and then called `\\Vendor\\User\\Models\\User` thanks